# Are there any Kimonolabs alternatives?

Tags: web-scraping, kimono

Recently kimonolabs announced they will be shutting down which is a major let down as my app heavily relies on this service in terms of getting data. It's really dissapointing that they're just shutting this service. I've been using import.io in the mean time but it's no where near the standard of kimono and is missing some features.

I was wondering if there are any services that are similar to kimono that have the following features:

- Scheduled crawls i.e. schedule a crawl every 24 hours or Alternatively you can call a link to update the latest data for a crawl.
- Bulk or single url crawls i.e. Enter a list or a single url to scrape.
- Call a link to get the results from the crawl in JSON.
- Use a single api key to make a call for the api.
- It's free for most of these features.

Alternatively i may be tempted to create my own it's just that i don't want to increase my dev time learning Node.js or Python which is why i'm asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

Update : December, 2018 - [Agenty](https://www.agenty.com/) is generally available now

If you are looking for <s>desktop app, Data Scraping Studio has the same plus more feature as in Kimono. Or you may install it on a windows server to make your own Kimono++</s> exact alternative

[image]

FYI : We also have plan to launch hosted solution and REST API by April, 2016

You may see more details on website <s>(www.datascraping.co)</s> now [Agenty.com](https://www.agenty.com/)

Disclosure : I'm one of the founding member

Comment: I was looking at this but there's no mac apps or a way to make api calls to get data. Also i don't have a lot of experience setting it up on a server so i'd like this to be done for me.

Comment: Also what will you be launching? Kimono++ or this data scraping tool

Comment: Hi Tunds, The only feature you are missing from that list, in import.io, is scheduled extraction. I'd be happy to show you how to switch a feature flag on to enable that feature in import, and how to use the rest of the features if you like. If you drop me a PM. Or email support@import.io and ask about scheduling a chained API and Bulk Extraction.

Comment: Mac app is not in plan right now. But we will be launching the hosted solution where you can login and start/schedule the extraction like Kimono and can also use REST API to make api calls.

Comment: @PrinceRathee Sweet could you send me a PM or do you have any dates as to when you think this will launch?

Comment: @Tunds Didn't decided the exact date yet, but most probably 1st week of April 2016. you may signup on datascraping.co and all user will get email when launched.

Comment: @PrinceRathee Sweet thanks for that mate :)

Answer (score 1):

Disclosure: I work at Scrapinghub, creators of Portia.

[Portia](http://scrapinghub.com/portia/), an open source, visual scraping tool that allows you to scrape by pointing and clicking on the web page you are trying to get data from.

There is a hosted version at [Scrapy cloud](http://scrapinghub.com/scrapy-cloud/), you can create an account for free and get:

- schedule your Portia Spiders through both Scrapy Cloud web UI and API.
- fetch items using API
- Use scrapy plugins (for example perform incremental crawls, download images to s3, etc).
- and others.

[Here](https://vimeo.com/129663101) you can see Portia in action

[Edit]
You can also port your kimonolabs project to portia automatically with this [tool](https://kimono.scrapinghub.com/)

Comment: Would i be able to do bulk urls?

Comment: If you mean set a bulk of start urls, yes you can.

Comment: Here is the doc: http://doc.scrapinghub.com/portia.html

Answer (score 0):

My team and I are working on a very similar tool and we will launch it soon. Here is more about it:

**Automatio** is **Web Automation Tool** which you can use to **scrape data** from any website in very easy way.

Some of the features are:

- Previewing scrapped data in different formats, like CSV, JSON, RSS, and API. There is download option as well.
- Generating widgets from same data and getting iframe output to display on your website.
- Visualizing data with different chart types.
- Supports regular pagination and infinite scroll
- Scheduling and looping tasks
- Integration with other platforms

If you are interested you can signup for **early access** here https://automatio.co

Check few videos to see it in action:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p-JdpnfuB58
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Cll_8-8a2s
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PsZY7tHE-K8